# jsViews and linkTo syntax

Tags: jsviews

I'm using jsViews to build a small app.
I have a input form section in which I want to provide a cancel button and a save button.

My goal is very similar to the [linkTo](https://www.jsviews.com/#link2way@linkto) section of the documentation.

However, my data-link is a bit more complex. I didn't find the correct syntax to bind data back to my editing object.

Here's what I have:

```
<input type="text" 
       data-link="{:Data.ListName:Editing.ListName}  
       id{:'txtListName_' + #getIndex()}" >
```

The textbox is populated with my backend data, but when I submit my form, I can't see the updated value. Neither in Data.ListName property nor in Editing.ListName.

I also tried:

```
<input type="text" 
       data-link="{:Data.ListName} linkTo{:Editing.ListName}  
       id{:'txtListName_' + #getIndex()}" >

<input type="text" 
       data-link="{:Data.ListName} linkTo=Editing.ListName 
       id{:'txtListName_' + #getIndex()}" >
```

But none of this works. The documentation is unclear regarding my issue.

What's the correct syntax ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to find the correct syntax, which is :

```
<input type="text" 
       data-link="{:Data.ListName linkTo=Editing.ListName:}  
       id{:'txtListName_' + #getIndex()}" >
```

Comment: Yes, correct. I will update the documentation to include: 
*Note that `linkTo` can also be used with the full syntax, and optionally with converters as in:* `<input data-link="{cvt:current.title linkTo=modified.title:cvtBk" />`

Comment: @BorisMoore: very kind. Thanks !